# Как отключить кнопку Fn?

Tags: linux

Всем привет)

Есть на ноуте такая кнопка Fn:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске Линукса она постоянно горит, что означает в приорете нажатия на F1-F12, хотя мне надо чтобы она при запуске никогда не горела и тогда будут работать регулировка звука и тд.

Собственно вопрос, как при запуске Пингвинчика сразу ее отрубать?

PS Тпряками прошу не кидаться, юзаю линукс всего дней 5 от силы и ещё не совсем всё знаю

### Xinput

```
┌──(dgdays㉿DGDays)-[~]
└─$ xinput
⎡     Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ A4TECH USB Device Consumer Control        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ A4TECH USB Device                         id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN9008:00 04F3:284E                     id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1201:00 04F3:30B8 Mouse               id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1201:00 04F3:30B8 Touchpad            id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣     Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD IR UVC WebCam: USB2.0           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD IR UVC WebCam: USB2.0           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ A4TECH USB Device Keyboard                id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ A4TECH USB Device System Control          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ELAN9008:00 04F3:284E                     id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ A4TECH USB Device Consumer Control        id=22   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

### ====================================================

```
Device 'Asus WMI hotkeys':
    Device Enabled (176):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (178): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (299): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (300):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (301):    0, 0
    Device Node (302):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (303):    0, 0
```

Comment: а как на ней написано, fn+esc, не работает?

Comment: @Fat-Zer На сколько я понимаю, `Fn`+`Esc` - этот вариант работает до перезагрузки

Comment: @Fat-Zer, работает, но хотелось бы, чтобы при перезагрузке она сразу оставалась отключенной

Comment: Заметил, у вас русская раскладка выгравирована после английской. Судя по фото вроде сделана добротно. Работал профессионал. Но гравировка сделана не на заводе, а в мастерской.

Comment: @DID, честно говоря, не в курсе Это ноут ASUS и он какой был при покупке в Мке, такой и остался

Comment: [Здесь](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107147/xmodmap-for-key-combination-how-to-toggle-the-fn-behavior) есть направление. Заодно станете "не совсем всё знать" заметно меньше :)

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, спасибо большое))) Как раз настрою неиспользуемые клавиши, на нужные)

Comment: @DGDays отпишите потом, получилось с xmodmap настроить неиспользуемые клавиши?

Comment: @DiD, настроить получилось, а вот сохранить нет((( То есть, при перезапуске они всё равно не пашут, а каждый раз через терминал делать - более геморойно

Answer (score 1):

- Идём в BIOS. Зажимаем нужную клавишу или комбинацию при включении ноутбука, какие конкретно жать кнопки зависит от модели устройства. Если нужно применить функциональную клавишу, нажатие `Fn` здесь не требуется, поскольку до старта ОС клавиши и так выполняют основные функции.
- Переходим к разделу *System Configuration*.
- Здесь ищем параметр *Action Keys Mode*, жмём `Enter`, значение с *Disabled* нужно изменить на *Enabled*.
  [image: CMOS Setup - System Configuration]
- На различных моделях устройств параметр может называться иначе (*Hotkey Mode*, *Function Keys Mode* и пр.) Для ноутбуков Dell идём на вкладку *Advanced* – параметр *Function Key Behavior* меняем значение c *Function Key* на *Multimedia Key*.
  [image: CMOS Setup - Advanced]
- Нажимаем `F10`, сохраняем изменение (`Yes`) и перезагружаемся.
  Теперь кнопки `F1`-`F12` будут функционировать в мультимедийном режиме, а для применения функциональных опций потребуется нажатие `Fn`.

Инструкция с незначительными правками взята отсюда: [Нaзначение функциональных клавишь, как изменить режим их использования в ноутбуке](https://nastroyvse.ru/devices/laptop/vklyuchit-otklyuchit-funkcionalnye-klavishi-v-noutbuke.html)

Comment: К сожалению, на моём ноуте есть только полное отключение этой клавиши. То есть, могу опять же пользоваться F1-F12, но теперь +- звук делать совсем не могу...

Comment: И что удивительно - Шиндовс запоминает в каком положении эта кнопка поставлена и оставляет её в томже при перезагрузке, а Линукс не хочет(

Comment: Дело не в Windows.

Comment: Windows просто уходил в особый вид суспенда, не выключая компьютер. в линуксе это надо настраивать.

Comment: не пользусь  Шиндой уже +-неделю и он до сих пор сохранил что у меня Fn+Esc были нажаты и выбраны функции мультимедии. А Линукс не хочет(

Comment: `xinput` какие устройства находит?

Comment: В вопрос добавил

Comment: посмотрите список доступных параметров `xinput list 20`

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Извиняюсь, неправильно  написал `xinput list-props 20`

Comment: Обновил. Смотрите

Comment: Попробуйте установить параметр `Send Events Mode Enabled (300)` в значение `1, 0` это что-нибудь поменяет в поведении клавишь?

Comment: `xinput set-prop 20 'libinput Send Events Mode Enabled' '1,0'` помоему, написал правильно (но это не точно) либо `xinput set-prop 20 'libinput Send Events Mode Enabled' 1 0`

Comment: Не найден девайс 300

Comment: Исправил. Точно, девайс 20

Comment: Всё как было - так и осталось. Fn по-умолчанию при рестарте включен. Кнопки мультимедии работают только при его отключении

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117165/discussion-between-did-and-dgdays).